# Matlab Coder - Alternative for strcat function

Tags: string, matlab, matlab-coder, codegen

Currently matlab coder is not supporting `strcat` or `strjoin`. Is there any anyway to circumvent this or custom function?

Edit:
Input= [a b c d]
Expected output= 'a,b,c,d'

Comment: `[` and `]` for `strcat`?

Comment: Probably relevant: [String functions supported by MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html#bq1h2z8-31)

Comment: What is the usage of `strjoin`? Example command?

Comment: @chappjc, strjoin also concatenate strings `str = strjoin(C,delimiter)` [matlab ref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)

Comment: @Joel I know the function, but I'm asking the specifics. What is the delimiter in your code?

Comment: @chappjc I was using comma as delimiter. `str=strjoin(c,',')`

Comment: @Divakar, can you explain how we can use `[]` for `strcat`? Doesnt that just make an array?

Comment: @Joel Doesn't `strcat` make a bigger array too? For example, `strcat('a','b')` and `['a' 'b']` are equivalent. But I don't know how you are using strcat, so can't guarantee that it's replaceable everywhere.

Comment: @Joel: There is no "string" in matlab. Everything is a row vector of characters. `[` and `]` should fix it in your case.

Comment: @Daniel For `strcat` it depends on inputs. Consider `strcat({'Red','Yellow'},{'Green','Blue'})`, which gives `'RedGreen'    'YellowBlue'`.

Answer (score 4):

For `strjoin` you might get away with `sprintf`:

```
>> colorCell = [{'Red','Yellow'},{'Green','Blue'}];
>> colorList = strjoin(colorCell,',')
colorList =
Red,Yellow,Green,Blue
>> colorList = sprintf('%s,',colorCell{:}); colorList(end)=[]
colorList =
Red,Yellow,Green,Blue
```

If you can't use `spintf`:

```
>> c = [colorCell(:) repmat({','},numel(colorCell),1)].';
>> colorList = [c{:}]; colorList(end)=[]
```

---

For `strcat`, simple usage is often equivalent to using `[]`.

```
>> strcat(colorCell{:})
ans =
RedYellowGreenBlue
>> [colorCell{:}]
ans =
RedYellowGreenBlue
```

However, for more complex syntax, it's not that simple:

```
>> strcat({'Red','Yellow'},{'Green','Blue'})
ans = 
    'RedGreen'    'YellowBlue'
```

Do you need a solution for this usage? Perhaps the following:

```
colorCell1 = {'Red','Yellow'}; colorCell2 = {'Green','Blue'};
colorCell12 = [colorCell1;colorCell2];
c = mat2cell(colorCell12,size(colorCell12,1),ones(size(colorCell12,2),1));
cellfun(@(x)[x{:}],c,'uni',0)
```

Comment: your solution allows to concatenate strings without using `strjoin` but unfortunately coder doesn't allow `sprintf` either.

Comment: Coder doesn't allow `cellfun` (at least as of 2015b which I can test), so that option is null too...